# Intellij doesn't work correctly with cloning project from github

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea

I have a problem with cloning repo from github. Already, I want to import project from my repository on the GitHub, so I run Intellij, I choose Checkout from from Version Control, next I use git repository url and I create existing project..
Everything is OK. Intellij gets this project from github, but when I use another branch from this repository, and I will modificate java class in this project, I have more problems, because anything work's correctly.
I cannot create a new class, all java files look like:
[image]

Hint's in Intellij doesn't work and I cannot appeal to another class in src package. I cannot run and debug this project too.

Comment: Do the problems persist after marking the directory as Source Root? (right-click folder > Mark directory as > source root)

Comment: It works much better, but now, all of import's doesnt work correctly. Jsonproperty cannot be resolved etc.

Comment: Sounds like some problems with your project structure. Make sure that all external libraries are added, or if you're using Maven, that maven dependencies are automatically imported, ...

Comment: I solved it. I clicked pom.xml and   -add to maven project , and it rebuilded my project and now is ok :) Thanks.